# How export core data store from iphone to Mac?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I can full iphone core data in iphone test at my phone
But i need this databases for all app copies

I need copy full databases to app folders
How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is pre-populating your database, yes? Well there is no straight-forward answer to your question in that case.

You can access the database file from your Simulator from `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[Version]/Applications/[AppID]/Documents`.

There is no way to my knowledge (without jailbreaking) to access the files on the phone.

There are many questions that cover pre-population right here on SO so I won't go through them all. You should be able to find what you are looking for by searching the site, if my answer wasn't enough.

Good luck.